# $f$ holomorphic, bounded on a disc then $\left| \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{M^2-\overline{f(0)} f(z)} \right|\le\frac{|z|}{MR}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is exercise, preparation to join a contest in next August.

It think, schwarz lemma will be useful. I haven't solved it yet. But

Show thatt if $f:D(0,R)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, with $|f(z)|\le M$ for some $M>0$ then

$$\left| \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{M^2-\overline{f(0)} f(z)} \right|\le\frac{|z|}{MR}$$

Comment: Yes, the Schwarz lemma **is** very useful for that. It's just a rescaling of it. (How do you obtain a function $g \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ from your given $f$?)

Comment: @DanielFischer Your comment could be an answer.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo You people really hate questions without answer here, don't you? Jesting aside, I wouldn't be comfortable to post an incomplete answer that merely gives a hint, and I'm not sure whether giving a full answer is the right thing to do here. Guidance?

Comment: I consider (but it's probably a personal opinion) that answers containing a relevant hint as yours are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Schwarz-Pick lemma, for a holomorphic funtion $h \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$, we have the inequality

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{h(z) - h(w)}{1 - \overline{h(w)}\cdot h(z)} \biggr\rvert \leqslant \biggl\lvert \frac{z-w}{1 - \overline{w}\cdot z} \biggr\rvert $$

for all $z,\, w \in \mathbb{D},\;\: z \neq w$.

Now, a function whose values are bounded by a constant $M$ is a function whose image is contained in $D(0,\, M')$ for all $M' > M$, so you can view your given $f$ as a holomorphic function $f \colon D(0, R) \to D(0, M')$ for all $M' > M$.

Then scale $f$ to obtain an intimately related function $h \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ from it. The remaining part is a simple calculation and a limit.